# Geo Replication on different tiers?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have an Azure SQL Database running in the S4 Tier in UK South and a read-only replica in Canada East running in the S1 tier.

Regarding the synchronisation of data, does a mismatch in tiers affect performance of synchronisation? If so, which tier "wins" in terms of speed of synchronisation? Or does the sync happen at the infrastructure level outside of any tier limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your S1 tier has fewer resources, especially in IO operations.
Keep track of resource usage on the primary and read-only replica.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```

Azure geo replicas are async, so during high activity times your replica may suffer from delays in syncronization.
Keep monitoring your log usage history using the above view so you can evaluate the IO workload and better tune the secondary tiers.